# Assigning to size_t when int is smaller than size_t

Tags: c, int, integer-overflow, size-t

Consider this code:

```
size_t s = 100000;
```

What happens if, on the platform where this is compiled, the `int` datatype is 16 bits wide and `size_t` is 32 bits wide? Will the `s` variable contain value 100000? Or the 100000 will be considered an integer, thus overflowing its 16 bits range, thus causing undefined behaviour and undefined value to `s`?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with "size_t" and everything to do with "how does a compiler treat an [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer literals always have type according to the magnitude of their value. If they're decimal (base 10, as in your example), the type is the first of `int`, `long`, or `long long` that's capable of representing the value. If they're hex or octal, the type is the first of `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long` or `unsigned long long` that can represent the value.

So, the relative size of `int` and `size_t` is not actually relevant to what happens in your question. As long as there is some signed type in which 100000 can be represented (and C guarantees there is; `long` must have at least 32-bit range), the literal has the correct value. Provided `size_t` is sufficiently large to represent this, the resulting value in `s` will be 100000. If `size_t` is smaller, the value will be reduced modulo `SIZE_MAX`+1.

Comment: _"Integer literals always have type according to the magnitude of their value."_ And how does this work with literals and arithmetic operations? For example, if `int` is 16b, does this `1000 * 1000` have value of 1000000 as `long`?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký: The literals involved there are `1000` and `1000`, which each have type `int`. They are operands in an expression using the `*` operator. Assuming 16-bit `int`, that overflows.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.